# How to completely remove href attribute from an a-tag conditionally with Thymeleaf?

Tags: thymeleaf

In a Thymeleaf template, I want to remove the `href` attribute depending on a given condition. I tried the following, but `href` still is present although without content:

```html
<a th:href="@{ ${ canUpdatePassword ? '/password/update' : _} }">Forgot password?</a>
```

To have the link completely removed from the browsers tabbing scheme, `href` must be ommited, so that the link gets marked as placeholder. How can I achieve this with Thymeleaf and not having any JS in place for that?

Many thanks

Comment: You could try returning null like this: `th:href="@{ ${ canUpdatePassword ? '/password/update' : null} }"` or `th:href="@{ ${canUpdatePassword} ? '/password/update' : null }"`

Comment: @WimDeblauwe Thank you for your response. Unfortunalely, this will still let the `href` attribute remain inside the tag, although its value is then empty `href=""`. As long as the attribute is there, the browser will not take the a-tag from its tabbing list (you still can access the link by tab key). Anyhow, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is probably just to use `th:if`.  I can't think of any other way to accomplish this.

```
<a th:if="${canUpdatePassword}" th:href="@{'/password/update'}">Forgot password?</a>
<a th:unless="${canUpdatePassword}">Forgot password?</a>
```

Comment: Yep, that's the way I ended up with. Only I didn't use `th:unless` but rather negating the boolean like `${!canUpdatePassword}`. Are there any downsides to the approach of negating? I think `th:unless` feels a little more complicated to wrap it up in my brain. Although I hoped for something more **inlineish** to not repeat the tag, I think I have to and can live with that. Many thanks for having a look into this.

Comment: No downsides to either approach.  Whatever feels better to you.